# Bathroom condensation

Tags: bathroom, mold, fans, condensation

My bathroom is mouldy and retains condensation on walls, windows etc. The room is approx 8fx7ft x 8ft high.

I’ve installed a new inline Manrose fan with timer to replace cheap old online fan, the Manrose extracts 245 cubic metres per hr.
The 100mm diameter flexi-duct run to the fan is 800mm and from the fan is 1000mm. Termination is a roof/ tile vent. Clean plastic flexi-duct which has been smoke tested and sound.

I’ve opened window to allow for replacement air but Even with 800x 200mm window open the steam builds up when using bath or shower.

What have I overlooked?

Can anybody help me with this issue?